# Ember.js global routed/transitioned events

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to subscribe to *all* transition events in the application? Or alternatively some observable property containing the current route?

I'm integrating with a third-party UI component that needs to be synchronized to the current route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by hooking into `Router.didTransition`

Live example: http://jsbin.com/yuzedacu/5/edit (modified the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182152/ember-nested-route-wont-show))

```
App.Router.reopen({
    updateCurrentRoute: function(infos) {
        var appController = this.container.lookup('controller:application');

        if (!('currentRoute' in appController)) {
            Ember.defineProperty(appController, 'currentRoute');
        }

        if (infos && infos.length > 0) {
            // The last part of the route contains the route name
            var route = infos[infos.length - 1].name;

            // Collect the dynamic route parameters
            var params = infos.reduce(function(a, b) {
                // Parameter can be named anything
                // assume there are 0 or 1 parameters
                for (var name in b.params) {
                    if (b.params.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        // 1 parameter
                        return a.concat(b.params[name]);
                    }
                }

                // 0 parameters
                return a;
            }, []);
            var path = [route].concat(params);
            Ember.set(appController, 'currentRoute', path);
        } else {
            Ember.set(appController, 'currentRoute', []);
        }
    },
    didTransition: function(infos) {
        this.updateCurrentRoute(infos);
        return this._super(infos);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The application controller has a `currentRouteName` property, as explained [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/). It's mostly for debugging, but I imagine that it's a fairly stable property that could be used in production.

EDIT: If you need to be alerted of *all* changes, use the [hashchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange) like Ember does internally. This will only work if you're using hash based routing though. If you're using Ember's history API based routing, you'll have to use that.

Comment: That gets me close but it only includes the static parts of the path, e.g. the `currentRouteName` for `users/fred` is `users/user`. The change event doesn't fire when switching between dynamic paths, e.g. transitioning from `posts/1` to `posts/2`.

Answer (score 0):

In your app_controller you can add this snippet which fires on every path/route change

```
currentPathDidChange: function currentPathDidChange() {
        var path = this.get('currentPath')
    }.observes('currentPath')
```

Comment: Just like `currentRouteName`, it doesn't fire when changing from `/posts/1` to `/posts/2`