# Ember nested route won't show?

Tags: ember.js, routes, nested

I've gone over the docs and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

**Router.map**

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){
    this.resource('user', { path: ':user_id' });
    this.resource('add');
  });
});
```

**handlebar**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="users/add">
  <h3>Add User</h3>
</script>
```

I get the proper URL with my link-to:
`{{#link-to 'add'}}Add User{{/link-to}}`

However the contents of my handlebar template for users/add never show?

**Here are my Routes**

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    console.log("Users route triggered");
    return App.Users; 
  }
});

App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return App.Users.findBy('id', params.user_id);
  }
});

App.UserAddRoute = App.UserRoute.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(){
    console.log("Users Add Route triggered");
    this.render('users/add'); 
  }
});
```

Here's my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/denap/3/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code had a few errors, as the `handlebars` template blocks are identified by `data-template-name` rather than by `id`. also you could declare `add` as a nested `route` than a nested `resource` - see your updated (& working) jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/yuzedacu/1/edit

Comment: Funny I had just figured it out before heading back here: 'route' instead of 'resource' .. jeez, always the little details.  Thanks so much though and regarding the id instead of data-template-name syntax, the latter is definitely more succinct yet I got into the habit of using id from ember guides.. not sure why they have both, but id does in fact work?

Comment: p.s thought your avatar was a killer whale diving back into the ocean

Comment: @micahblu I checked it back and indeed the `handlebars` script blocks are also recognized when using `id` instead of `data-template-name`... cool! I always thought my avatar is a batcat, but it seemst that it's some sort of pokemon ;)